# In Redux, what is the benefit of using actionCreators?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm currently learning Redux and I have hit a snag, my question is why do you require actions where the application works without them? What do they add?

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

// ACTIONS
const addTodo = (text) => {
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  text
}

const toggleTodo = (id) => {
  type: 'TOGGLE_TODO',
  id
}

// REDUCER
const todos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: state.length,
          text: action.text,
          complete: false
        }
      ]
    default:
      return state
  }
}

// STORE
const store = createStore(todos)

// TEST
store.dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TODO', text: 'Test' })
console.log(store.getState())
```

Comment: You can see actions as the _"glue"_ between the react components and the store.

Comment: Do you mean action creators? As in why do you need addTodo when dispatch({ type: 'Add_TODO', text: 'Test'}) works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't get confused between **ActionCreators** and **Actions**, they're different things.

**Actions** are just objects with a `type` property (*and anything else you want to add*).

**ActionCreators** build the actions according to provided logic and data.
For example, suppose an action "updates a contact", then the action creator might be built as a thunk for async flow, it would dispatch the network request to the API to update the contact and once it knows the API call worked, it dispatches the action, which could be something like:

```
{
  type: "UPDATE_CONTACT",
  data: { prop: "newValue" }
}
```

**Using CONSTANTS** this is a convenience for maintenance/debugging on larger code bases. By using constants your environment will be quicker to flag a misspelled Action because the const would not exist. Where as if you rely purely on object literals or strings, it could be more complicated to debug.

**Why use action creators**

ActionCreators are used for 2 main purposes:

Portability & testability [as per the redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html)

I've also found them useful for dynamically building the final action data. As per my above example, in a case where you would POST a contact, the server would usually respond with a LOCATION header, giving you the new location (*and possibly ID*) of the contact, which you will need for future GET or PUT requests. Using an actionCreator, I can bundle that new data into the final action object, which would then look something like:

```
{
  type: "CREATE_CONTACT",
  data: {
    first_name: "bob",
    last_name: "builder"
    id: 7         // -> provided by API, the actionCreator injected it
  }
}
```

Comment: I was referring to the action creator.

Comment: edited answer to provide more info about actionCreators